# Unmount gvfs fileserver which does not show up in 'gvfs-mount -l'

Tags: ssh, mount, gvfs

I am working on a remote server that runs CentOS 7.4.1708. On this server, I managed to mount a fileserver, which is in the same network, with the following commands that I found somewhere on the internet:

```
export $(dbus-launch)
gvfs-mount smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/abc/
```

Now I was able to access the files at

```
/run/user/100*/gvfs/smb-share\:server\=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/\,share\=abc/
```

Once I finished moving files etc., I usually unmounted the server:

```
gvfs-mount -u smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/abc/
```

Now the problem is, that **I forgot unmounting and just closed the ssh connection** to the CentOS server. Once I logged in again, I could still access the fileserver at `/run/user/100*` and that directory still showed me as the owner. However, `gvfs-mount -l` does not show the fileserver anymore and trying to unmount it results in the following error message

```
Error finding enclosing mount: Containing mount does not exist
```

**Edit:** Remounting of the fileserver does not work, the `gvfs-mount` job does not finish within 10 minutes and seems to do nothing.

**How can I unmount the fileserver now?** (I have no sudo rights)

Comment: Did you try remounting, then unmounting?

Comment: @user2679290 Yes, remounting does not work, 'gvfs-mount smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/abc/' does not finish within 10 minutes, I don't know whats happening, but after some waiting, I killed the job.

Comment: Well, you know, get the admin somehow or launch a debugger and fogure out where it fails